# how to contribute on open source project featuring python

Tags: python, open-source

I know python and want to contribute on OpenSource projects that features python. Anyone can help me where to contribute and how.

I already googled it and find github and code.google as a good place to contribute but how to start it I don't know.

Suggest how to get started.

Comment: 1. Find the repository on GitHub or Google code. 2. Contribute.

Comment: Don't go looking, use a few python open source packages like a regular user.. appreciate it and if you find any short comings then try to fix it yourself and send a pull request to the author. That way you will learn and make meaningful contribution, not without experience the package first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is an appropriate question for SO - you might get voted down. But ...

Whenever I have seen this question, the answer is almost always:

1. find a project you like / you're interested in
2. find something in that project that you feel you can fix / enhance (have a look through their bug tracker)
3. fork the project (github makes this easy)
4. make the change, find out what is appropriate for that project (documentation, unit tests, ...)
5. submit the change back to the project (github has "request pull")

Good luck!